# Update a CSV file to drop the first number and insert a decimal place in a particular column

Tags: csv, awk, sed, replace

I need help to perform the following

My CSV file looks like this

```
900001_10459.jpg,036921,Initiated
900002_10454.jpg,027964,Initiated
900003_10440.jpg,021449,Initiated
900004_10440.jpg,016650,Initiated
900005_10440.jpg,013929,Initiated
```

What I need to do is generate a new csv file to be as follows

```
900001_10459.jpg,3692.1,Initiated
900002_10454.jpg,2796.4,Initiated
900003_10440.jpg,2144.9,Initiated
900004_10440.jpg,1665.0,Initiated
900005_10440.jpg,1392.9,Initiated
```

if I was to do this as a test

```
echo '036921' | awk -v range=1 '{print substr($0,range+1)}' | sed 's/.$/.&/'
```

I get

```
3692.1
```

Can anyone help me so I can incorporate that, (or anything similar) to change my CSV file?

Comment: So it's OK to drop a leading zero in the result?  On the face of it: `awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } { $2 /= 10; print; }'`, but that omits the `.0` after `1665`.  How much does that matter?  Will there ever be numbers with more than one leading zero?  Without a leading zero?  With more than 6 digits?

Comment: Not all leading zeros. Just the left most zero. I wish to have 4 numbers (including zeros) and the last value (5th value) separated from the 4 values by a decimal point. For example, numbers like 000669, would need to change to 0066.9

Comment: Then the `sed` solution proposed by @Bohemian is appropriate — it's a pure string manipulation problem, not a numeric problem.  It can be done with `awk` but you end up using `printf "%s,%06.1f,%s\n", $1, $2 / 10, $3` to print the values (and you don't do the `/=` operation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk` and with the conditions specified in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67310444/update-a-csv-file-to-drop-the-first-number-and-insert-a-decimal-place-in-a-parti#comment118975638_67310444), you can use:

```
$ awk -F, '{ printf "%s,%06.1f,%s\n", $1, $2 / 10, $3 }' data
900001_10459.jpg,3692.1,Initiated
900002_10454.jpg,2796.4,Initiated
900003_10440.jpg,2144.9,Initiated
900004_10440.jpg,1665.0,Initiated
900005_10440.jpg,1392.9,Initiated
$
```

With the `printf` format string providing the commas, there's no need to set `OFS` (because `OFS` is not used by `printf`).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sed 's/,0*([0-9]*)([0-9]),/,\1.\2,/' myfile.csv
```

Comment: Given the requirement to remove only one zero, the `*` after the `0` is not required.  And even GNU `sed` (4.2.2 tested) requires either `-E` or `-r` to activate extended regular expressions; macOS `sed` needs `-E` and doesn't support `-r`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that values with leading zeros appears solely in 2nd column I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
900001_10459.jpg,036921,Initiated
900002_10454.jpg,027964,Initiated
900003_10440.jpg,021449,Initiated
900004_10440.jpg,016650,Initiated
900005_10440.jpg,013929,Initiated
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",0?";OFS=","}{$2=gensub(/([0-9])$/, ".\\1", 1, $2);print}' file.txt
```

output

```
900001_10459.jpg,3692.1,Initiated
900002_10454.jpg,2796.4,Initiated
900003_10440.jpg,2144.9,Initiated
900004_10440.jpg,1665.0,Initiated
900005_10440.jpg,1392.9,Initiated
```

Explanation: I set field separator (`FS`) to be `,` optionally followed by `0`, so leading zero will be discarded as part of separator. In 2nd I replace last digit by . followed by that digit. Finally I `print` such changed line, using `,` as separators.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

> `I wish to have 4 numbers (including zeros) and the last value (5th value) separated from the 4 values by a decimal point`.

If I understand, you need not all digits of that field but only the last five digits.

Using `awk` you can get the last five with the `substr` function and then print the field with the last digit separeted from de previous 4 by a decimal point, using the `sub()` function:

```
awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '{$2= substr($2, length($2) - 4, length($2) ); sub(/[[:digit:]]{1}$/, ".&",$2);print}' file
900001_10459.jpg,3692.1,Initiated
900002_10454.jpg,2796.4,Initiated
900003_10440.jpg,2144.9,Initiated
900004_10440.jpg,1665.0,Initiated
900005_10440.jpg,1392.9,Initiated
```